# How can I get security event log general details from EventViewer?

Tags: c#

I want to write a Windows application that takes all details of security event logs for all objects (user, computer, group) in windows server 2008.

**for example** I want to retrieve following data from `create user(with this eventId:4720)` of the user object:

- SubjectAccountName
- TargetAccountName
- SamAccountName
- UserPrincipalName
- Computer
- CreationTime

and other details

This is my code that give me public details such InstanceId, source , …

```
 EventLog myNewLog = new EventLog();
 myNewLog.Log = "security";             

 foreach (EventLogEntry entry in myNewLog.Entries)
    listBox1.Items.Add(entry.TimeWritten + "\t" + entry.InstanceId.ToString() + "\t" + entry.Source);
```

but I want to know how I can get details in general tab like SubjectAccountName , SamAccountName , UserPrincipalName , computer ,...

Comment: your question is not clear...what is the problem?can you write code here?

Comment: Do not put code in comments, delete your old comments and [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29793011/edit) with the code showing what you tried.